# Wireless button to trigger py script on raspberry pi

Tags: python, wifi, bluetooth

I'm looking for ideas and products that would enable me to run this setup with a raspberry pi:

---

I'm looking for a **wireless** wifi or bluetooth button that can be paired or connected to a raspberry pi on the local network that when the raspberry pi recieves the signal that the button has been pressed, it can run a task of my choice, such as an .sh or .py script.

I'm looking for wireless wifi or bluetooth buttons that will work with this and some code that corresponds with this button to run what I want when the button has been pressed.

Thanks very much, if you need any more info, let me know. All suggestions appreciated.

Buttons, senders, receivers, code - all things I'm looking for

Oliver

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here ... asking for confimation that a device exists is ok ... yes, bluetooth buttons do exist ... you could also hack a wireless keyboard... remove the keyboard portion and connect a switch ... would not have to be bluetooth ... a remote control for wifi lights may also work

Comment: Also look at doorbells using 433Mhz - decoders are available in software and receivers are very low cost.

Comment: @jsotola The keyboard idea is pretty cool, I like that a lot. Cheers

Comment: @Andrew So Id' just get a button using 433 and make sure the receiver is too? Any software examples or code examples to make that work with a reciever? Very new to this. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ekv_56 Doorbells / key fobs etc encode a reasonably unique signal onto the 433 carrier (that's why you often have to 'pair' doorbells and you do not ring the next door bell) Using a general receiver (eBay / component supplier) is fine - look at https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils for software and a google for 433 doorbell decoding or 'the man with the Swiss accent' https://youtu.be/oYfbEyzT-Gs should give pointers galore.